# PHPPresentation - How to customize filename of served (downloadable in browser) file to not be the filename of the invoking php script?

Tags: php, phppresentation

How do I modify the following script (Summary.php) so that the served PPTX file name is not "Summary.php" and my served file is not named Summary.php.pptx?

The technique I am using is to render contents of the PowerPoint file into into the browser but I intentionally want to change the filename to at least not contain .php, but at best be a custom name like Presentation.pptx as specified in my php header below.

**Summary.php**

```
require_once 'vendor/phpoffice/phppresentation/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Border;


class Presentation
{
    function generatePresentation()
    {
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation; filename=Presentation.pptx");
        $oWriterPPTX = IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPhpPresentation,'PowerPoint2007' );
        $oWriterPPTX->save('php://output');
    }
}
```

EDIT

**Solution**

```
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Presentation.pptx");
    $oWriterPPTX = IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPhpPresentation,'PowerPoint2007' );
    $oWriterPPTX->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Content-Disposition` response header. E.g.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Thank You,  I modified my header statement to be two separate headers instead.  See edits.  My file generated is the correct filename.